# What rule is at work here?

Tags: tense, irrealis-mood

I don't understand the use of "did" here. I am confused whether it should be did or does.

> I wonder what my speech would be. And if Bill would help me with it if he **did**n’t go to New York and write plays.

Also will the construction with "will" be

> Bill **will** help me with it if he doesn’t go to New York.

It's from "Perks of Being a Wallflower". Bill is Charlie (the narrator)'s teacher. The book is in the form of letters written by Charlie (not to Bill). In previous letter Charlie mentioned that Bill wants to go to New York and write plays but the decision isn't final.  Now in this letter Charlie is imagining future. He's thinking about graduation speech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence is talking about an imagined future, based on some condition being different. In this construction, Charlie is considering the future moment of writing this speech and wondering whether Bill will be helpful. At this moment, in the hypothetical, Bill is already in New York or not in New York, so Charlie's use of 'didn't' instead of 'doesn't' reflects the past tense of this imagined future. 'Hadn't gone' and 'wasn't going' both imply that Charlie knows Bill will go, which may not be the case in the uncertain future of the Charlie's actual present.

> I wonder what my speech would be [if .....]. And [I also wonder] if Bill would help me with [my speech] [in the case that he doesn't] go to New York and write plays.

I agree with you that if he knew that Bill would help him if Bill were in town, he could say "Bill will help me with it, if he doesn't go to New York".

Comment: Bill would help me if he didn't go [all the time] to NY. Unlikely.

Comment: Sorry? What do you mean

Comment: Ok, let's try it another way. There is no imagined future at all. This is the conditional: If X, then Y. But for it to be conditional as written, it would have to refer to habitual action. Bill would help me if he didn't go to NY all the time [or every week or every month].

Answer (score -3):

The rule at work is **poor AmE spoken English:**

SAMPLE:  I wonder what my speech would be. And if Bill would help me with it if he didn’t go to New York and write plays.

It should be:

- I wonder what my speech would be. And if Bill would help me with it if he **hadn't gone** to New York to write plays. [one possibility: he went]

OR:

I wonder what my speech would be. And if Bill would help me with it if he **wasn't going to** New York to write plays. [another possibility: we was going to go]

**CONDITIONAL**: this is all conditional:
He **would** help me, if he **didn't go** to NY [all the time, habitual action].

**The sentence above is unlikely.** **It is only grammatical if it is habitual. There is no indication of that.**

Comment: I don't think it's a fair or useful judgment to call it 'poor' spoken English. Also, the original sentence is using 'if he didn't go' in talking about the future to indicate that Bill hasn't certainly gone or not gone, so 'hadn't gone' is a less accurate replacement than 'wasn't going'.

Comment: @L.B. It is poor;  I would not know, if he didn't go.  You can't use "If he didn't go" to talk about the future. It is an conditional: If he didn't go, where is he?

Comment: Where he already was. I think 'can't' is a strong word for something I absolutely have heard people do in real life.

Comment: How do you know it's bad English? It could mean he regularly goes to New York and writes plays, in which case this ***"did"*** would be the correct tense.

Comment: "I would help you if you didn't go to school every day". [habitual action], that's fine. But it is very **unlikely** that it's: Bill would help me, if he didn’t go to New York [all the time or habitually) and write plays (as a general proposition). That's why.

Comment: @L.B. Conditional tenses have no future in them. I wish people wouldn't downvote when they do not understand the grammar.

Comment: Hey personally I didn't even downvote you but if we're wishing I wish you wouldn't prioritize a really limited (limiting!) set of standard grammatical conventions over the natural language as it's successfully used by people who have spoken it their entire lives- for example me / some guy who wrote a bestselling book which was later made into a movie with Emma Watson in it (neither here nor there). Some people asking questions on here are really into grammar details & I respect that but a lot of people just want to speak the real live language and the prescriptivism isn't always useful. My 2¢.

Comment: @L.B. You don't understand what I am saying. There is a difference between explaining grammar to an English-language learner, and how a sentence reads. Regardless of whether some author is a best-selling one or not. Very often the ones who cry prescriptivism the loudest are the ones who actually understand the utterances the least. *The second clause has to be habitual for it to make sense*. For example:  If he didn't write plays for a living, I'd help him. Or I'd help him, if he didn't go to NY every week.

Comment: If your answers weren't so judgmental (accepting that other views besides yours can be correct) you would get less downvotes.  I know you have gotten this feedback before and still you have not modified your behavior to accept and act on good-faith criticism.  The answer's format could also be improved, this is not a clear and easy to read explanation.

Comment: @mjjif When I see people telling me that "If he didn't go" is talking about a future, I despair. When I see people invoking accuracy based on the fact an author writes best-sellers, I despair. "I wonder if you would help me in case you don't go to NY and write plays". for me is not grammatical in English. And I don't mean prescriptively. "would help" cannot be paired with a simple past to mean future. "I wonder if you would help me if you have time". As for behavior modification, not sure that is relevant. If people vote based on that, they are poor sports.

Comment: I would accept: If he hasn't gone to NY to write plays, I wonder if he would help me.

Comment: The way you manage to completely miss the point of my comment and double down is baffling.  What causes you despair is irrelevant in this space.

Comment: @mjjf There's nothing wrong with me making a judgment about the English language in some book. Maybe the author did it on purpose; but my point stands, there is no future here, it is a failed conditional sentence. The only way to know for sure, is to ask the author. Nevertheless, it is not clear. Let's try another example: **I wonder if John  would help me if he didn’t go to New York". OK, but not: if he didn't go to New York and write plays.